# How to make a operating system with html?

Tags: html, linux, assembly, operating-system

So I am currently working on a project for school. It is more of a experiment just to test my knowledge of computers. So basically I have tried a few things. I have tried basic assembly but all I could manage was to put hello world on the screen. I then tried to use CosmosOs with c# but to make a gui and file system is almost impossible. Finally I am at my last choice which is to make a distro of linux that runs a html script full screen at start. Although this won't be 100% pure, it still would allow me to make a nice looking gui for the O.S. Is there anyway I can do this? Is there other ways I can make a o.s. out of html? Thank you very much. I hope I can get help

Comment: I don't see what using HTML for a login-screen image(?) for a Linux distro has to do with `[assembly]`.  If you write a GUI as an HTML form, you'd still need to write or use a web server and process requests, so you still need an OS for that to run on.  And you'd need an HTML renderer.  This sounds about as far from 100% pure asm as you can possibly get, like 0.1% your own OS if you write a management gui as a CGI server on top of GNU/Linux + Firefox or Chrome or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean HTML for UI, rest is with c/c++ like language ?
then you can use HTML rendering engine like Webkit/blink, or QT.
You can not implement all the thing using HTML.

Comment: Yes. I was thinking of that. Thank you.

Comment: check yoga-layout also which is using react-native to generate cross platform UIs which is written in C++, but unfortunately I couldn't find C++ api examples

Answer (score 1):

HTML is not an operating system control language.
Give up on that as an option.

Comment: I meant using html as a ui.

Comment: @MarkRatcliffe It is possible, but good luck getting an HTML rendering engine ported to your new system.